# How to run .exe file from matlab

Tags: matlab

I got a .exe file complied by Fortran, which is for converting one format to another one. I have to run it lots of times and each time with different input.  I could able to run the exe file with below script

```
command=('C:\Program Files\Director2.exe < O:\Free\1.dat');
system(command);
```

until now every thing is fine but when the GUI is comes up plus input data, I should chose the format and new directory for saving the conversion. I would like to know, is there any way to do that? Indeed I don't wanna use java.awt.Robot class which is not work for me [(GUI automation using a Robot)](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/gui-automation-robot/).
Also I have check this post, which has not been helpful.
[(How to run .exe file from matlab)](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/241352)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why does not `java.awt.Robot` work? Post your code. Maybe it can be fixed

Comment: Indeed, I am using my computer at the same time then probably there would be some interruption which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point

Comment: So the program has no command line options? Is it possible to modify the source code to add those, possible making it a pure command line program? If the conversion is not very complicated, you could also consider translating it into Matlab.

Comment: Unfortunately this program is a commercial program which is like protected code and does not have command line option or any way to have access. That's the reason I am challenging with that.

Comment: If it is a commercial program without a command line your only option is to use some kind of GUI manipulation library like java robot. You will not be able to use your computer without interruption, anytime you have to manipulate a GUI it will need access to the mouse, keyboard, etc.